# Can I use MariaDB instead of MySQL in wordpress?

Tags: database, mysql

Is it possible to use MariaDB instead of MySQL in Wordpress installation? 
If possible: how do I do that?
Is there any drawback or complexities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your exact questions:

- Yes.
- Just use MariaDB instead of MySQL.
- No, it is a straight replacement.

The exact details depend heavily upon your exact situation. However, MariaDB is marketed as a compatible MySQL replacement. AFAIK, it works with WordPress with no changes at all.

Comment: Certainly it seems to be a drop-in replacement. It now ships with Fedora Linux distros, and when I upgraded from Fedora 17 to 19 my WordPress websites just kept on working. (Maybe I ran a mysql_upgrade on them, but otherwise, no difference)

Comment: MariaDB ships with a dozen or so *nixes that I am aware of, some of them big players. I strongly suspect MariaDB to replace MySQL in the (surprisingly) near future.